# How to allow chaining to JS methods

Tags: javascript

I have created my own JS library. In that i have defined various methods like this:

```
Dome.prototype.find = function(els) {
       for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          var findselector = this[i].querySelectorAll(els);
       }
       return this[i] = findselector || ''; 
   }

Dome.prototype.addClass = function (classes) {
    var className = "";
    if (typeof classes !== 'string') {
        for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
           className += " " + classes[i];
        }
    } else {
        className = " " + classes;
    }
    return this.forEach(function (el) {
        el.className += className;
    });
}
```

When i call find or addClass method it runs fine. But if i call like this:

```
dome.get('body').find('h1').addClass('class_name');
```

it gives error dome.get(...).find(...).addClass is not a function.

Can anyone tell me how to allow chaining to these methods?

Comment: Return the instance from the method.

Comment: Your `find` function returns a string... I gues you want to return `this`

Comment: `find` will never return a string, but instead always assigns the collection returned from the *last* iteration (if any) to the *last* value of `i`, and returns that. The `|| ''` does nothing. What were you actually wanting to return? There's nothing here that'll have a `.find()` or `.addClass()` method, unless you `return this`.

Comment: ...and why the object wrapper approach? It was handy when IE6/7 were relevant since the host objects couldn't be extended in the typical prototypal way. But today, it's just overhead for little benefit.

Comment: If i put like $('body').find('h1') then its returning me all h1 tags. But if i return this its returning me all h1 tags with body tag. So when i am calling $('body').find('h1').addClass('class_name') then className is adding to body tag @squint

Comment: If you want `$("body").find("h1")` to return all `h1` in the `body`, then for the `$` call you'd probably want to add the `body` to the object, then for the `.find()`, you'd iterate all the elements (the body) in the previous object and either replace the current items with the new elements, adding them at each `i` index, or you'd create a whole new object.

Comment: ...either way, these object wrappers have lots of overhead, maintenance, side effects and sometimes unintuitive behavior. All just so you can do method chaining, which is really pretty unimportant, IMO.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it? @squint